# Why is the if statement executing?

Tags: python-3.x

```
chessBoard ={'1h':'bking','3e':'wking'} 

def isValidChessBoard(board):
   bking=0
   wking=0
   for v in board.values():
       #bking=0
        if v == 'bking':
            bking = bking + 1
       #wking=0
        if v== 'wking':
            wking= wking + 1
   if bking or wking > 1:
            print('This board is invalid')
   else:
            print('Board is good')


isValidChessBoard(chessBoard)
```

Hello, everyone. Does anyone have some insight as to why the if statement is executing? It is my understanding that because both bking and wking are less than 1 it should go to the else statement?

Comment: `or` doesn't work like that. Should've been `bking > 1 or wking > 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `or` is formatted incorrectly.

Change `if bking or wking > 1:` to `if bking > 1 or wking > 1:`.